# Как найти и присвоить переменной картинку?

Tags: java

---

## Задача присвоить переменной картинку

Создали переменную - `private Image img;`

Картинка которую мы должны присвоить переменной

Лежит по пути `src/assets/img.png`.

#### Требуется это для вывода картинки в окно JPanel с помощью Graphics

---

Буду рад любым ответам.

Зарание спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Что вы потом планируете с ней делать? Что именно вам нужно от картинки — её содержимое, путь до неё, её имя, мета-данные? Что конкретно вы хотите поместить в переменную?

Comment: Я планирую поместить данную картинку в переменную которую указал выше

Comment: Что вы хотите с ней сделать после того, как поместите её в переменную? Работать с ней как с изображением, просто как с файлом, или вообще как со строкой? Суть вашего вопроса не ясна.

Comment: Как с изображением конечно.

Comment: Вы уже попытались проявить самостоятельность и поискать материалы/открыть главу в учебнике как это делается? Вы далеко не первый, кто хочет открыть картинку в яве и примеров по этой теме достаточно. А сейчас вы просто требуете от нас скопировать сюда общедоступную информацию, которую вы сами не потрудились поискать.

Comment: Да. Поискал и все что мне удалось найти вот - qaru.site/questions/20896/how-to-set-an-image-as-a-background-for-frame-in-swing-gui-of-java/ | и у меня не получилось сделать по их ответом. Поэтому я и обратился сюда.

Comment: Это какой же заковыристый поисковый запрос нужно составить, что бы найти только одну странную ссылку, которая к тому же вообще про другое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Image img = new Image(<Ваш класс>.class.getResourceAsStream("/assets/img.png")
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы планируете работать с этим изображением, вам надо в переменую заносить дескриптор изображения. 
Вот [статья](http://www.mstu.edu.ru/study/materials/java/18.htm) по работе с изображениями в Яве.

Если вы просто хотите в переменную поместить пачку байт, которые будут интерпретироваться как изображения вам надо открыть его как файл и полностью считать.

Comment: Прочитав статью данную вами мне. Я так и не разобрал как и что делать. Можно Если вы просто хотите в переменную поместить пачку байт, которые будут интерпретироваться как изображения вам надо открыть его как файл и полностью считать. перенести пожалуйста в код.

Comment: Тут нечего переводить, вы просто считываете картинку как обычный файл и все, я просто не осведомлён как в Java работать с файлами.

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо. Вопрос решен вот так:

ImageIcon iib = new ImageIcon("img.png");

img = iib.getImage();